# ¿ Como hacer con IIS + Visual Studio que paginas con extension "html" la lea como si fuera "aspx"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

Cuando se programa con php y servidor de paginas web Apache es posible que las paginas con extensión .html y .php las trate por igual pudiendo haber código en php dentro de una pagina con extensión .HTML
¿ Es posible configurar el servidor de paginas web IIS + visual studio para que cuando vea una extensión .HTML pueda haber código en .aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sacado de una [respuesta](https://serverfault.com/a/283445/351845) en inglés:

En IIS7, escoger como grupo de aplicaciones el modo clásico y luego ir a la parte de asignación de controladores. Anotar todas las entradas que tengan como ruta de acceso: .aspx y crear unas iguales para .html

Luego añadir lo siguiente en web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
   <add path="*.html" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
</httpHandlers>
```